# What best describes "you hurt your finger because you accidentally squeeze your finger when you unfold your headphones"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

[image]

Look at my headphones, I can  fold / unfold them (see the picture). Sometimes I squeeze my finger accidentally at the interface when I unfold them. The 2 edges press a bit of my finger's skin a little hard and that hurts a little but causes a sudden hurt.

What best describes "**you hurt your finger because you accidentally squeeze your finger when you unfold your headphones**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably going to be locale-specific, but without doubt I would call this a "nip", i.e. "I just nipped my finger in the hinge of my headphones".

Comment: "PInch" is less locale-specific.